# Connecting to the built-in Anylogic DB

Tags: hsqldb, anylogic

I've been using Anylogic's feature to collect data to a database provided by the program. 
However I have trouble extracting the data again. I've tried using the export to excel function, but the program is getting stuck (probably because of the large amount of data).

Now I'm looking at connecting directly to the database. Anylogic provides me with a connection string:
    `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/nau_sterilcentral;file:C:\Users\nbn\Models\NAU sterilcentral\database\db`

I only use the first part (until the `file:C:\...`) since DBeaver doesn't ask for more. My connection string i DBeaver looks like this: `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/nau_sterilcentral`

I expect the db to be running since i can query it from Anylogic, but I'm not sure. When I try to connect i keep getting an error:

```
connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
  org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know AnyLogic, but:

HSQLDB needs to be started in server mode to allow a connection from a different process. If AnyLogic starts HSQLDB in embedded mode, you can't access the database as long as AnyLogic is running.

Also the JDBC URL needs to be **either** a server URL using `localhost:9001` **or** a "local" URL containing a file name, you can **not** mix both things (and the syntax for the file based URL was wrong as well)

Assuming AnyLogic starts HSQLDB in embedded mode, you *have* to stop AnyLogic, then you can connect using a file based URL. The syntax for that would be:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:C:\Users\nbn\Models\NAU sterilcentral\database\db
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I had to tweak DBeaver since it wouldn't let me select a file, but only a path.